# Travis CI with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: javascript, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I have a web application http://codefu-5euzxjdg6b.elasticbeanstalk.com/codeKungfu.jsp that is currently being hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with a Java backend.

The flow process that I have in mind is this:

- Commit to GitHub repo
- Travis CI is triggered. Run unit tests.
- All test cases pass. Deploy on Amazon elastic beanstalk.

Currently, I am stuck at Step 3, where I am attempting to link up Travis CI with Amazon elastic beanstalk.

I have searched for information online with regards to this but was unable to find anything that seems to be useful. The best information source that I obtained was:
https://superuser.com/questions/510593/elastic-beanstalk-rails-application-with-git-source-and-deploy-hooks

I understand that Travis CI is able to deploy to Google App Engine directly, and thus I believe that there should be a solution for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk as well.

Could anyone kindly point me to resources that could potentially help me solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

As of 9th Dec 2014, Elastic Beanstalk deployment is not covered in Travis CI deployment documentation:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/

However, Travis CI has open sourced their deployment tool: **dpl** and Elastic Beanstalk deployment is an ongoing development:
https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl

It's best to refer to the source itself to figure out how to do the deployment.

At present, here's a working sample of my deployment settings in .travis.yml:

```
deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  access_key_id: <AWS Access Key>
  secret_access_key:
    secure: <secure secret access key>
  region: <region, eg. ap-southeast-1>
  app: <app name>
  env: <environment name>
  bucket_name: <S3 bucket name that is used by elastic beanstalk>
  on:
    repo: <repo name>
    branch: develop
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this should definitely be the accepted answer. Just setup this exact thing and it is working like a charm. Thanks @Jon

Comment: Hey! How did you encrypt the `secret_access_key`? Because usually you need to provide a key/value pair when encrypting things on Travis. What did you enter as encryption key when you generated the `secure` value for your AWS Secret Access Key?

Comment: You can refer to the documentation here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/

Comment: @Jon What is `bucket_name: <S3 bucket name that is used by elastic beanstalk>`? Where I can find it?

Comment: @user606521, you can find it as one of the S3 buckets. Click on the S3 service and look for a bucket that starts with `elasticbeanstalk-`

Comment: I used this sample just now and had a successful deploy on first try. Travis' output did say it's still experiemental. Here's my config https://github.com/maxbeatty/passplum/commit/12055821bbd5fb5027bfca078719d790a26db19f

Answer (score 2):

Did you end up making progress on this? I think that it should be possible with Travis's encrypted variables to store a key or your AWS credentials. Then you could use those credentials with the AWS API to do the deploy itself from within your .travis.yml after_script section.